Prove the hosting provider's server slowness in a shared web hosting
Starting 11/09/2024 my website performance decreased after the hosting provider migrated the site to a cloud-based server.
The issue occurs when transitioning from HTTP to HTTPS (about 1 or 2 seconds) and between the initial user URL request and the execution of the page's PHP script (from 0.5 to 20+ seconds).
Before that date, pages loaded in less then 300 milliseconds. They are  simple PHP script generating static HTML (99% text).
The issue occurs randomly even when accessing a very simple page containing only 10 pure HTML lines, without any PHP statement inside it and with no redirect or other stuff.
I always have the option to switch to a different hosting provider except that I have already paid for some future years of subscription...
How can I gather evidence to prove that the website slow performance is due to the hosting provider server?
Edit:
Page Speed Insight says that performance is 100. The problem is that the slowness doesn't happens constantly but randomly. I tested with pingdom with a case of speed of 20 seconds for a only few html text page... The location of the server changed from Italy to Brussells but I think that the real problem is their new cloud based infrastructure (e.g. the load balancer or their network handler)

This could be more accurately re-phrased "what data should I collect to use for comparison when there is a performance problem?" For any web site really.

@GregAskew I prefer the actual new title, because it clearly explains the real cause of the problem and many others users are everyday facing that problem. It can also help other users when they search for that on google

The only real way to test the speed of a hosting provider is to monitor the speed of web pages. There are lots of site that can do this for you. Just google: "monitor web hosting speed", or something similar. The problem is knowing what is fast and what is slow. Since you didn't measure the speed before the move you don't really have anything to compare it with. However, you could rent another price-comparable server for a short time, put your stuff on it, and measure that. Then you have something to compare it with.

Performance testing on a shared hosting is complicated, because you usually don't have many available tools to measure or view internal performance.
However, there are some things you can do to help you troubleshoot.

Do you have cPanel or CWP installed? Either tool can give you a CPU usage and memory breakdown. It may even show details such as running processes, or other diagnostic information.
Do you have a database in place? Perhaps an index is corrupted and needs maintenance, you need new indexes to perform better, or one of your tables needs repairing. If using MySQL, you can turn to phpMyAdmin to do this maintenance. If using other databases, you should have some software to manage it.
Why are you transitioning from HTTP to HTTPS? Perhaps a redirect is faulty.
Can you install a monitoring tool? Probably not if in shared hosting, but how about setting up an external one? There are many out there that can help you.
Can you pinpoint if it happens during a particular time of day? Perhaps a cron job is hurting your performance, a long-running job, or your backups.
Can you restart (or request a restart) of your server? It can be that some process has hanged up and is clogging up your server.
Are you enabling caching on your application? Can you so that you serve 100% static files? Does it make a difference?
How about load-balancing, or using a CDN? Cloudflare is great for this, and could give you a speed boost if properly configured.
Are your DNS correctly configured? A bad configuration can in some cases cause weird behavior resulting in repeated lookups (and thus, increased latency).

I've tried to narrow down things you can usually do on a shared hosting to diagnose and help you determine the culprit.


they replaced cPanel with their proprietary WePanel (a shame...)
for my tests I'm using a php page with no lines of php nor db access
because not all users use directly https
unfortunately not, can you please tell me some external tool? I'm trying pingdom
I have no cronjob; maybe the server has some
even after the restart, the same processes will cause the same slowness after some time
all my website is made by my own code hand written, no plugin, no framework, no cache needed
I cannot use a load balancer, they have one for sure
how to check for that?
Thanks


for 8) I would try CloudFlare.com You will get a performance boost even on a free account. for 9) I would try IntoDNS.com - it will analyze your DNS and give you a report.

When you say in 6) that after some time the slowness returns, that may point to a script leaving open processes or not closing connections timely. Or perhaps the PHP version has changed. One way to find out is to try pure HTML pages vs. PHP pages, and see if there's a significant difference. Enable logging all errors in your PHP configuration to see if you catch anything that needs fixing.

I completely agree with Kiko Software.
Once again, I recommend checking your site on the current server using Google’s tool — Page Speed Insight.
If it shows that the slowdown is indeed on the server side, and as I understand, you already have data from before the migration, simply present this comparison to the support team.
Secondly, could the server locations have changed? It might be worth looking into, although I doubt it could have much impact.

Page Speed Insight says that performance is 100. The problem is that the slowness doesn't happens constantly but randomly. I tested with pingdom with a case of speed of 20 seconds for a only few html text page... The support team is incompetent or lies... maybe the location of the server is changed from Italy to Brussells but I think that the real problem is the new cloud based infrastructure

@user2342558  Maybe you should add the above comment to the question as this narrows down stuff.    It sounds like you have multiple issues - possibly including DNS lookups - And if Page Speed Insight says things are working fast, maybe the issue is not with your provider - How does Lighthouse (built into Chrome - I suspect related to Page Speed Insight but run from your browser) break down the page load times?

@davidgo added. The issue is 100% due to the provider because the dns was warking very fast also before their server switch (is SquareSpace, ex Google domains dns). I tested by reading the hosting logs raw accesses that the http request arrived to the hosting many seconds before it reached the php page! I'll try Lighthouse, thanks
